# I want to understand growth over time of specific customer groups

Tags: customer-group

How do I query my SQL database in order to pull this information? I have a tool that's connected into my database, but have to write a specific query in order to pull in the data.

Help. Noob here when it comes to code - I'm the marketing guy.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to understand growth over time of specific customer groups

My understanding of this requirement is that you want to find out how/when customers where assigned to customer groups. This is not possible as Magento does not store the date/time when a customer was assigned to a specific customer group.